Access the tkinter widget properties from callback function
I have a function, lets call it create_window,where I created a tkinter window with only a label and a button. I have a command which calls a callback function, lets call it change. I can not access window components from change function. This is a sample:
import tkinter as tk
def create_window():
    window = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(window, text="Label!")
    label.pack()
    button = tk.Button(window, text="Change", command=change)
    button.pack()
    window.mainloop()
def change():
    label.config(text="Label changed from click!")
create_window()


If I create window in main code, I can access the window widget normally. Any ideas?
I got this error when I click a button:
NameError: name 'label' is not defined

Local variables inside a function cannot be accessed outside that function.
For you case, you can pass the label to change():
def create_window():
    ...
    button = tk.Button(window, text="Change", command=lambda: change(label))
    ...

def change(label):
    label.config(text="Label changed from click!")


Thank you, using lambda function as a callback allowed me to pass label object to change() function.
